# Undefined symbol "_mcount" when cross-compiling for aarch64

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, arm64, gprof

I'm trying to use gprof for a project that runs in a small embedded OS (https://github.com/smartobjectoriented/so3). Compilation for this OS is done using the "aarch64-none-linux-gnu-" toolchain (version 11.3.Rel1) and uses a musl libc and cmake. I've added the "-pg" option to both build and linking of my application using

> target_compile_options(letter_count.elf PRIVATE -pg)

> target_link_options(letter_count.elf PRIVATE -pg)

However when I try to build, I get this error

> aarch64-none-linux-gnu-ld: CMakeFiles/letter_count.elf.dir/letter_count.c.obj: in function `count_letters':
> /home/anthony/Repositories/so3/usr/src/letter_count.c:25: undefined reference to `_mcount'

It happens at linking time so the build seems to understand the "-pg" option (and adds the "_mcount" symbol) but not the linker. Is the _mcount symbols not available in this toolchain ? Or is there another mistake I may have made ?

Comment: It seems musl maintainers [have not implemented](https://www.openwall.com/lists/musl/2014/11/05/2) this part of Glibc.

Comment: You're using the wrong toolchain. If you use musl, you need `aarch64-linux-musl`, not `-gnu`.

Comment: @yugr Thanks for the info. So it really is a libc feature. I found somewhere that contrary to clang, gcc's -pg was standalone but it would make sense that the libc has to provide some work for timer and file support

Comment: @SIguza I'm using the toolchain that is supported by the OS I'm using but I'll check with the maintainer if a musl toolchain is usable

Comment: @AnthoJack so the maintainer is building musl itself for a non-musl ABI? That sounds... very bad.

Comment: It works...at least for everything except what I'm trying to do here